# Major differences between Lucene.Net 2.9 and 3.0

Tags: lucene.net

I have been snooping around trying to find some release notes for Lucene.Net 3.0 and so far have been unsuccessful.  Currently we use Lucene.Net 2.9, but its a memory hog so I am trying to find out if Lucene.Net 3.0 has improved memory management.

As for my question, what are the major changes in 3.0?  Has the memory management been improved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [CHANGES.TXT](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_3_0_3_RC2_final/CHANGES.txt) in the source distribution.

```
=================== Release 3.0.3 2012-10-05 =====================

Bug
•[LUCENENET-54] - ArgumentOutOfRangeException caused by SF.Snowball.Ext.DanishStemmer
•[LUCENENET-420] - String.StartsWith has culture in it.
•[LUCENENET-423] - QueryParser differences between Java and .NET when parsing range queries involving dates
•[LUCENENET-445] - Lucene.Net.Index.TestIndexWriter.TestFutureCommit() Fails
•[LUCENENET-464] - The Lucene.Net.FastVectorHighligher.dll of the latest release 2.9.4 breaks any ASP.NET application
•[LUCENENET-472] - Operator == on Parameter does not check for null arguments
•[LUCENENET-473] - Fix linefeeds in more than 600 files
•[LUCENENET-474] - Missing License Headers in trunk after 3.0.3 merge
•[LUCENENET-475] - DanishStemmer doesn't work.
•[LUCENENET-476] - ScoreDocs in TopDocs is ambiguos when using Visual Basic .Net
•[LUCENENET-477] - NullReferenceException in ThreadLocal when Lucene.Net compiled for .Net 2.0
•[LUCENENET-478] - Parts of QueryParser are outdated or weren't previously ported correctly
•[LUCENENET-479] - QueryParser.SetEnablePositionIncrements(false) doesn't work
•[LUCENENET-483] - Spatial Search skipping records when one location is close to origin, another one is away and radius is wider
•[LUCENENET-484] - Some possibly major tests intermittently fail 
•[LUCENENET-485] - IndexOutOfRangeException in FrenchStemmer
•[LUCENENET-490] - QueryParser is culture-sensitive
•[LUCENENET-493] - Make lucene.net culture insensitive (like the java version)
•[LUCENENET-494] - Port error in FieldCacheRangeFilter
•[LUCENENET-495] - Use of DateTime.Now causes huge amount of System.Globalization.DaylightTime object allocations
•[LUCENENET-500] - Lucene fails to run in medium trust ASP.NET Application

Improvement
•[LUCENENET-179] - SnowballFilter speed improvment
•[LUCENENET-407] - Signing the assembly
•[LUCENENET-408] - Mark assembly as CLS compliant; make AlreadyClosedException serializable
•[LUCENENET-466] - optimisation for the GermanStemmer.vb‏
•[LUCENENET-504] - FastVectorHighlighter - support for prefix query
•[LUCENENET-506] - FastVectorHighlighter should use Query.ExtractTerms as fallback

New Feature
•[LUCENENET-463] - Would like to be able to use a SimpleSpanFragmenter for extrcting whole sentances 
•[LUCENENET-481] - Port Contrib.MemoryIndex

Task
•[LUCENENET-446] - Make Lucene.Net CLS Compliant
•[LUCENENET-471] - Remove Package.html and Overview.html artifacts
•[LUCENENET-480] - Investigate what needs to happen to make both .NET 3.5 and 4.0 builds possible
•[LUCENENET-487] - Remove Obsolete Members, Fields that are marked as obsolete and to be removed in 3.0
•[LUCENENET-503] - Update binary names

Sub-task
•[LUCENENET-468] - Implement the Dispose pattern properly in classes with Close
•[LUCENENET-470] - Change Getxxx() and Setxxx() methods to .NET Properties
```

Comment: I found this as well after I downloaded the new dll.  In my experience the Index rebuild time was abit more stable, but wasn't really worth the effort to upgrade.  I didn't notice much improvement in regards to memory, but hopefully Lucene.Net will get to v4.0 in the near future.